# When adding a friend, it change status/button my side but not another side

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, pusher

When I add a friend it change status/button my side but not another side. 
I am using Pusher, Laravel and Vue.js.

My problem is that if am sending friend request it will send to other user and notify to me but not to other side. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

This is my channel code.

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id){
return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

This is my NewFriendRequest.php code

```
<?php

   namespace App\Notifications;

   use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
  use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
 use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class NewFriendRequest extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
use Queueable;

public $user;

/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail','broadcast','database'];
}

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->line('You received a new friend request from ' . $this->user->name)
                ->action('View Profile', route('/profile', ['slug' => $this->user->slug]))
                ->line('Thank you for using our Tictac!');
}

/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'name' => $this->user->name,
        'message' => $this->user->name . ' sent you friend request.'
     ];
}
}
```

This is my notification.vue code

```
<script>
  export default {
        mounted() {
              this.listen()
        },
        props: ['id'],
        methods: {
              listen() {

                    Echo.private('App.User.' + this.id)
                        .notification( (notification) => {
                              noty({
                                      type: 'success',
                                      layout: 'bottomLeft',
                                      text: notification.name + notification.message,
                                      timeout: 5000
                              }).show()

                              document.getElementById("noty_audio").play()
                        })




              }
        }
  }
```

This is my Example.vue code that can use to send friend request to 
       other user.

```
  add_friend(){
      this.loading = true
        axios.get('http://localhost/Tictac/add_friend/' + 
    this.profile_user_id )
        .then ((r) => {
          if(r.data == 1)
          this.status = 'waiting'
        new Noty({
          type: 'success',
          layout: 'bottomLeft',
          text: 'Friend request sent .',
          timeout: 5000

          }).show()

          this.loading = false
        })

      },
```

My bootstrap.js file

```
   import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

   window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

   window.Echo = new Echo({

 authEndpoint: 'http://localhost/Tictac/broadcasting/auth',
 broadcaster: 'pusher',
 key: '58f16da7e24fa9505db8',
 cluster: 'eu',
 encypted: true



  });

  Pusher.log = function(message){
  window.console.log(message)
  }
```

App.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

 window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));
Vue.component('notification', require('./components/Notification.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app'
});
```

Comment: Are you saying that the broadcast notification is not being received on the JavaScript side by the User?

Comment: yes...! it is sending from my side but not to receive other side..

Comment: Have you set BROADCAST_DRIVER to pusher in `.env`: `BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher`

Comment: i have also set

Comment: Try adding: `Pusher.log = function (message) {window.console.log(message);};` in `app.js` and you should get some output from pusher in the console. You may also need to add the `cluster` in your setup.

Comment: i use this in bootstrap.js

Comment: Fair enough, add it to `bootstrap.js` you should still get the same result.

Comment: but not to get same result..

Comment: my notification save in to database but not show to receiver side

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the code for `bootstrap.js` and `app.js` so I can see what you are doing.

Comment: i have edited my question and code of bootstrap.js and app.js